# Magento integrity constraint violation: 1062 on creating configurable product

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, configurable-product

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4-81' for key 'UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_super_attribute` (`product_id`, `attribute_id`) VALUES (?, ?)
```

Hi,

I'm getting the above error when trying to add a configurable product to my 1.9.2 CE installation. I have checked the database and this isn't actually a duplicate entry. I've tried resetting all the catalog product tables, including auto increments but the error persists.

I have also tried clearing all caches, reindexing and disabling all third party modules (although none of these should be affecting the product saving).

The only mention of this error I can find online is due to people writing custom product save code, but this is using the core functionality.

Does anybody know how I can fix this please?

Many thanks

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: For anybody else finding this in future: I think this is related to the ebizmarts Mailchimp4Magento module. I have opened a forum thread here: https://ebizmarts.com/forums/topics/view/21855